# How to optimize and faster for loop when handling large dataset in R?

Tags: r, loops

Currently, I'm working on the data transformation. The data is not super large, about 190k rows.

I wrote a for loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
#a
record.a <- df[which(df$first_lat==df2[i,"third_lat"] 
            & df$first_lon==df2[i,"third_lon"] 
            & df$sixth_lat==df2[i,"fourth_lat"] 
            & df$sixth_lon==df2[i,"fourth_lon"] 
            & df[,4]==df2[i,4] 
            & df[,3]==df2[i,5]),]
df2[i,18] <- ifelse(nrow(record.a) != 0,record.a$order_cnt,NA)

#b
record.b <- df[which(df$fifth_lat==df2[i,"third_lat"] 
            & df$fifth_lon==df2[i,"third_lon"] 
            & df$sixth_lat==df2[i,"second_lat"] 
            & df$sixth_lon==df2[i,"second_lon"] 
            & df[,4]==df2[i,4] 
            & df[,3]==df2[i,5]),]
df2[i,19] <- ifelse(nrow(record.b) != 0,record.b$order_cnt,NA)

#c
record.c <- df[which(df$fifth_lat==df2[i,"first_lat"] 
            & df$fifth_lon==df2[i,"first_lon"] 
            & df$fourth_lat==df2[i,"second_lat"] 
            & df$fourth_lon==df2[i,"second_lon"] 
            & df[,4]==df2[i,4] 
            & df[,3]==df2[i,5]),]
df2[i,20] <- ifelse(nrow(record.c) != 0,record.c$order_cnt,NA)

#d
record.d <- df[which(df$third_lat==df2[i,"first_lat"] 
            & df$third_lon==df2[i,"first_lon"] 
            & df$fourth_lat==df2[i,"sixth_lat"] 
            & df$fourth_lon==df2[i,"sixth_lon"] 
            & df[,4]==df2[i,4] 
            & df[,3]==df2[i,5]),]
df2[i,21] <- ifelse(nrow(record.d) != 0,record.d$order_cnt,NA)

#e
record.e <- df[which(df$third_lat==df2[i,"fifth_lat"] 
            & df$third_lon==df2[i,"fifth_lon"] 
            & df$second_lat==df2[i,"sixth_lat"] 
            & df$second_lon==df2[i,"sixth_lon"] 
            & df[,4]==df2[i,4] 
            & df[,3]==df2[i,5]),]
df2[i,22] <- ifelse(nrow(record.e) != 0,record.e$order_cnt,NA)

#f
record.f <- df[which(df$first_lat==df2[i,"fifth_lat"] 
            & df$first_lon==df2[i,"fifth_lon"] 
            & df$second_lat==df2[i,"fourth_lat"] 
            & df$second_lon==df2[i,"fourth_lon"] 
            & df[,4]==df2[i,4] 
            & df[,3]==df2[i,5]),]
df2[i,23] <- ifelse(nrow(record.f) != 0,record.f$order_cnt,NA)
}
```

So, basically, I need to fill out 6 columns of df2 respectively from df with 6 criteria. In the for loop, nrow(df2) is about 190k. It runs super slow. But I used view(df2) to check it and it runs fine. So is there any method I could make it faster? I may apply the same data transformation to a much larger dataset in the future.

df:
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5zQD.png)

df2:
[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDIfd.png)

The data is about grids on a map. df2 is basically a subset of df but add 6 additional columns. Both df and df2 has the same lon and lat information.

Each grid_id stands for a hexagon area in a map. Each hexagon is connected to other six hexagons by two pairs of lon and lat. What I want to do is that find a particular values from the six surrounding hexagons (in df) to fill into columns (a, b, c, d, e, f) in df2. Also, I need two other conditions, which is hours, ten_mins_interval. (df[,4]==df2[i,4] & df[,3]==df2[i,5]))

So I think the logic is:

1. For each grid_id, hours, ten_mins_interval (1 row) in df2
2. find the corresponding 6 grid_ids (6 rows) with same hours, ten_mins_interval in df
3. fill order_cnt from those 6 rows into a,b,c,d,e,f columns in df2

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example, e.g. pasting the output  `dput(head(df))` and `dput(head(df2[,18:23]))` in the question.

Comment: for loops are nearly are nearly always unnecessary, but you need to share some sample data and expected results to make it easier to understand what you need. Maybe also simplify the problem - fewer columns

Comment: At the moment you're unlikely to get a complete answer to this because the problem is not reproducible, i.e. there is no example data showing the structure of df and df2. The most likely way to speed this up seems to be to use the `merge` function for each of the 6 blocks to avoid the `for` loop

Comment: Thank you for your responds. I just edited my post to add more information. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with your current `df2[,1:17]` you can add `df[,18]` with the merge command:

```
df2 <- merge(df[,c("first_lat","first_lon","sixth_lat","sixth_lon","col4name","col5name","order_cn")],
      df2,
      by.x=c("first_lat","first_lon","sixth_lat","sixth_lon","col4name","col5name"),
      by.y=c("third_lat","third_lon","fourth_lat","fourth_lon","col4name","col3name"),
      all.y=TRUE)
```

You'll need to replace `col4name` with the name of the fourth column and so on - I can't see from the screenshot what that might be. Five more versions of this command can be easily generated to add the other five columns. As the operation works on whole vectors at time, it's likely to be faster than looping. As data wasn't provided in a suitable format this isn't tested.